# Using Proximity tool in QGIS 2.16

Tags: qgis, proximity, distance-matrix

I am using the proximity algorithm to generate a raster proximity map indicating the distance from the coast (points shapefile) of my study area and the center of each planning units (I have divided my study area in almost 5000 square planning units).
I would like to know the difference between the following values I have obtained:

-distance count;
-distance sum;
-distance mean;
-distance minimum;
-distance maximum.

and which one I should consider in order to understand the importance of the distance from the coast to each planning units.